# create categories on RSS feed using java

Tags: java, rss, rome

I want to create an RSS feed using a JAVA application (using ROME), and got it to work OK, till i decided to use some categories.
I use this code for the categories

```
public boolean addRss(String cat,String msg,String msgLink,Date date){
        SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
        List<SyndEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SyndEntry>();
        SyndEntry entry;  
        entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
        entry.setTitle(msg);
        if(msgLink!=null){
            entry.setLink(msgLink);
        }
        List<SyndCategory> categories = new ArrayList<SyndCategory>();
        if(cat!=null){
            SyndCategory category;
            category = new SyndCategoryImpl();
            category.setName(cat);
            categories.add(category);
            entry.setCategories(categories);
            categories.remove(category);
            entries.add(entry);
        }
        entry.setPublishedDate(date);
         entries.add(entry);
         feed.setEntries(entries);
        return true;
    }
```

but this doesnt include any category tag on the output xml file.
any ideas? thanks

**Edit**
It seems that using the same piece of code on the creation of the RSS (and not the creation of the Item, as i did before) it does work. I can now add a category tag on the RSS file, but it implies for the whole of the rss feed, i.e for all the items that follows. so i cant create an rss feed that has items from multiple categories

Comment: Why are you removing the category after adding it? `categories.remove(category);`

Comment: to be honest, i am not so sure, I cant remember. We changed our rss format, so we dont use categories no more, but for the life of me, i cant remember this piece of code.thanks for your input though, this might be a good reason for not working in the first place

Comment: Ok :) because it is possible to have different categories for each item. Your code example probably didn't  work because of the remove() -call.